# Make sure a generic parameter isn't a primitive

Tags: java, generics

I'm writing some code where I want to have a generic parameter, but it can't be a primitive.  **Is there a way to make sure a generic parameter to a function isn't a primitive?**

For example,  if I have the following function which checks if the parameter is an integer (using `Integer` because `int` doesn't have `.getClass()`).:

```
public static final <E> int len(E e) {
    Integer i = 0;
    if (e.getClass() == i.getClass()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I wanted to keep going for every primitive, this function would be very long (no pun intended).  In essence, can I prevent a primitive object from being passed into a function with generic parameters?

Comment: Aside: `Integer` is not premitive!

Comment: I know that.  The point is that you can't use `.getClass()` with an `int`.

Comment: How about listing your unwanted class type and check if the passed parameter is among those types?

Comment: @Ian So I would have a `List<Object>` with an instance of each class I don't want.  Then I would iterate with `.getClass()`?  Seems like a smart way to do it.

Comment: It is one way of doing it... then you could use instanceof to check... but there might be some issues with inheritance... please check.

Comment: by the way there's no point for the type parameter `E` here; you can just declare it as `public static final int len(Object e)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's *never* a primitive. If a primitive is passed in, it will be autoboxed to the appropriate wrapper class, eg `int` -> `Integer`.

---

Regarding your statement *int doesn't have .getClass()*...

Actually, `int` *does* have a class: `int.class`, but it is mainly used by the reflection api to represent method parameter types or return types of `int`.